# I attempted to use tf.TextLineReader to read data line by line, but olny odd-numbered line was read in

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, read-data

I attempted to use tf.TextLineReader to read text dataset, but olny odd-numbered line was read in. I don't know why. How should i do to make it read data line by line?

```
import tensorflow as tf
filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer(["./data/all_c_dev.en"])

reader=tf.TextLineReader()
key,value=reader.read(filename_queue)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()
    for i in range(10):
        print(key.eval(),value.eval())
```

[running result](https://pic1.zhimg.com/v2-6d904f1e8e3e7e73537dc45f18ae37f7_r.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `key.eval()`, you're updating both `key` and `value`. Then, when you call `value.eval()`, you're updating `key` and `value` again.

You can fix this by updating both variables in a single call to `sess.run`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()
    for i in range(10):
        k, v = sess.run([key, value])
        print(k,v)
```